# How to sum values each row in csv which belongs to specific object?

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I have this csv:

```
ProductID, Price
P1, 10
P1, 19
P2, 68
P3, 18
P1, 20
```

How to sum total price of each ProductID, the result like this:

```
ProductID, Total
P1, 49
P2, 58
P3, 18
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What have you tried? You should show what you've done and ask questions about the parts that failed.

Comment: sorry that I relied you lately. yes I have tried and because I'm new with pandas package so I'm stuck with this :(  @JustinEzequiel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the data into pandas and then use a group_by sum combination.

```py
import pandas as pd

pandas_data_frame = pd.read_csv('path_to_csv_file')

pandas_data_frame.groupby(['ProductID']).sum()
```